# Micronaut rules for choosing between multiple possible endpoints?

Tags: java, micronaut

What rules does Micronaut use to decide between the following 2 endpoints when responding to a HTTP request?

```
@Get(value = "/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}")
public HttpResponse<?> getSomething(String param1, String param2, String param3){
    ....
}
 
@Get(value = "/{param1}/not_a_param1/not_a_param2")
public HttpResponse<?> getSomethingElse(String param1){
    ....
}
```

A request GET /hello/not_a_param1/not_a_param2 could match to either endpoint - how does Micronaut decide which one is right? (From testing I've done Micronaut seemed inconsistent, sometimes choosing one or the other, and never giving the '*More than 1 route matched the incoming request*' error message listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499188/micronaut-2-0-0-more-than-1-route-matched-the-incoming-request)).

I'm testing against Micronaut 3.2.0. Googling hasn't come up with any obvious answer.

Comment: "From testing I've done Micronaut seemed inconsistent, sometimes choosing one or the other" - That is surprising.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues with a sample app, we can investigate.  Thank you for the feedback!